# What's the logical difference between PostQuitMessage() and DestroyWindow()?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

In my demo kinda app

```
case WM_CLOSE:
    DestroyWindow(hndl);
    return 0;
```

and

```
case WM_CLOSE:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;
```

do the same. What's different behind the curtains when calling each? Is DestroyWindow more direct, where as PostQuitMessage has to go through the getmessage loop returning false?

Comment: Consider what might happen in an application which has multiple windows. `DestroyWindow` destroys a window. `PostQuitMessage`... posts a quit message: that is, it indicates that the entire application wants to quit.

Comment: @jalf, I was *just* editing that into my answer :p

Comment: @chris and I just upvoted your answer. :)

Comment: When you're new to the Win32 API, it's not immediately obvious where the line is drawn between "my window" and "my application". The message pump API really isn't very clear or helpful there. But it is important to realize that a distinction exists between the two. Do you want to close the window, or exit the application?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`DestroyWindow` destroys the window (surprise) and posts a `WM_DESTROY` (you'll also get a `WM_NCDESTROY`) to the message queue. This is the default behaviour of `WM_CLOSE`. However, just because a window was destroyed does not mean the message loop should end. This can be the case for having a specific window that ends the application when closed and others that do nothing to the application when closed (e.g., an options page).

`PostQuitMessage` posts a `WM_QUIT` to the message queue, often causing the message loop to end. For example, `GetMessage` will return 0 when it pulls a `WM_QUIT` out. This would usually be called in the `WM_DESTROY` handler for your main window. This is not default behaviour; you have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 17):

Neither snippet is correct.  The first one will do what the default window procedure already does when it processes the WM_CLOSE message so is superfluous.  But doesn't otherwise make the application quit, it should keep running and you'd normally have to force the debugger to stop with Debug + Stop Debugging.  If you run it without a debugger then you'll leave the process running but without a window so you can't tell it is still running.  Use Taskmgr.exe, Processes tab to see those zombie processes.

The second snippet will terminate the app but will not clean up properly since you don't pass the WM_CLOSE message to the default window procedure.  The window doesn't get destroyed.  Albeit that the operating system will clean up for you so it does all come to a good end, just without any bonus points for elegance.

The proper way to do it is to quit when your main window is destroyed.  You'll know about it from the WM_DESTROY notification that's sent when that happens:

```
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So from my understanding the DestroyWindow() function in WM_CLOSE checks if it's the main application window (parent window) that shall be closed, and if true, it issues a WM_DESTROY message. Otherwise only the (child) window itself is closed and the application keeps running.

Comment: No, any window will send WM_DESTROY when it gets destroyed.  Windows itself gives no particular preference to a window, it is also fine with an app having no window at all.  So it is your job to be interested in the *specific* window that sends that message. And if it is your main window that got destroyed and none are left then you should quit your program since the user can't do anything useful anymore.  Which you do by calling PostQuitMessage when you get WM_DESTROY for that window.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm misunderstanding, but if effectively every time a window (child for example) is closed, it sends a WM_DESTROY, wouldn't that always mean that you exit the loop and quit the application? Where's the logic that issues the PostQuitMessage(0) exclusively if the WM_DESTROY comes from the main window?

Comment: A child window has its own window procedure, it doesn't use yours.

Comment: omg of course, how did I confuse that. Sorry for all those questions

Answer (score 0):

PostQuitMessage doesn't necessarily mean the end of application. It simply posts WM_QUIT to the message loop and allows you to exit from the message loop, so in most cases, this means the end of the application. However, in a multithread application, if you have the message loop for each thread created, PostQuitMessage only closes that thread.

As a side note, if you ever need more lines of code to execute after the message loop (such as further clean-up), PostQuitMessage is a better way to go, because DestroyWindow destroys the window without going through the message loop, ignoring whatever clean-up codes remaining after the message loop. Some may call it a not-so-good coding practice, but sometimes you can't avoid situations like that.