# WinApi task killing

Tags: c++, winapi, task

I have super simple WinApi program. Close button does not destroy process of the program. What should be added?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

HINSTANCE hINSTANCE;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
               HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
               LPSTR lpstr,
               int nCmdShow) {

// VARIABLES
    TCHAR className[] = _T("win32api");
    TCHAR windowName[] = _T("Protected Window");

    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_INFORMATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_BACKGROUND;
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = className;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_SHIELD);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Cannot register window"), _T("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return 0;
    }

     HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(className,
                              windowName,
                              WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                              CW_USEDEFAULT,
                              CW_USEDEFAULT,
                              300,
                              300,
                              NULL,
                              NULL,
                              hInstance,
                              NULL);

    if (!hWnd) {
        MessageBox(hWnd, _T("Call to register windows isn't working"), _T("Error"), NULL);
        return 1;
    }

    hINSTANCE = hInstance;
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0) != 0 || GetMessage(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0) != -1) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.lParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uInt, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    switch (uInt) {
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        TextOut(hdc, 10, 20, _T("Text sample right here boyz."), _tcsclen(_T("Text sample right here boyz.")));
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uInt, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I add one more case

```
case WM_CLOSE:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
```

It doesnt close at all (pressing close button is not doing anything). Any other tips are very appreciated.

Comment: [DestroyWindow destroys the window..](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16749227/2142994) Does this help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your message loop is wrong, for two reasons:

1. you are calling `GetMessage()` twice.  Don't do that!  Think of what happens if you do.  If the `GetMessage()` call on the left-hand side of `||` were to detect `WM_QUIT` (which it can't, see further below), it would return 0.  Which would cause `||` to call the `GetMessage()` on the right-hand side, ignoring the `WM_QUIT` from the previous call and blocking the loop until a new message arrives later.  You should call `GetMessage()` only once per loop iteration, and then act on the return value as needed:

   ```
   BOOL bRet;

   do
   { 
       bRet = GetMessage(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0);
       if (bRet == 0) break;
       if (bRet == -1)
       {
           // handle the error and possibly exit
       }
       else
       {
           TranslateMessage(&msg); 
           DispatchMessage(&msg); 
       }
   }
   while (1);
   ```
2. However, you are also filtering messages by `HWND` ([don't do that!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050209-00/?p=36493)), and so it will only return messages that are posted to the specified `HWND` via `PostMessage()`.  `PostQuitMessage()` posts its `WM_QUIT` message to the input queue of the calling thread itself, not to the `HWND`.  So the filtering will never see the `WM_QUIT` message.  In order for `WM_QUIT` to break the loop, you need to stop filtering by `HWND` altogether, or at least make an unfiltered call periodically.

Your message loop should look like this instead.  This is the *standard* message loop:

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Note in this case, [there is no need to handle -1 from `GetMessage()`!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130322-00/?p=4873).

Answer (score 0):

To close the app, you need to destroy the window. Typically that's done in one of two ways:

1. Have your `WM_CLOSE` handler call `DestroyWindow`.
2. Have the `DefWindowProc` handle the message after you do your thing.

Your `WndProc` is a little out of the ordinary. I usually see them written as:

```
{    
    switch(msg) 
    {  
        case WM_CLOSE:
            // prompt user, clean stuff up, etc.
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
           PostQuitMessage(0);
           break;

        // Other cases here. Most will fall out of the switch so that
        // DefWindowProc can handle them (for other system notifications).
        // Only return from the case if you really don't want anybody else
        // to handle the message.
    }

    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

For specifics on `WM_CLOSE`, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617(v=vs.85).aspx, which specifically says that you must call `DestroyWindow` or let `DefWindowProc` do it.

Comment: You mean that `WndProc` should contain just`switch` discribing behavior after actions performed with window? How should I put buttons, etc. then?

Comment: As I recall, you put the button handling stuff in the `WM_COMMAND` handler.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just a beginner. I can't understand how it works. If I put them into `WM_COMMAND` case then it doesn't appear in program. So I need to force `WM_COMMAND` case to work somehow? And more, how WndProc is called by the program? And how messages come from OS to GetMessage? And what WM_PAINT should contain?

Comment: @RomanKorol: This answer didn't solve your issue. The [answer by Remy Lebeau](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36872144/1889329) did, and you should make that clear by accepting that answer instead of this one.

Comment: @RomanKorol: You need an introductory book on Windows programming. The questions you're asking are too broad to cover in a comment response.